# How can i get the id from a user that is creating an object and use it in the creation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In my code i have a 'User' model and an 'ONG' model, a user has one ong and the ong has an 'user_id',
so when the User creates an Ong i want to get the user(that is creating) id and insert into the Ong user_id column

The user can only create an Ong if he is logged in

Ong model

```
public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
```

Ong migration

```
        Schema::create('ongs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('ong_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->smallInteger('user_id');
        });
```

User migration

```
        if(!Schema::hasTable('users')){
            Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('name', 100);
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
                $table->string('password', 80);
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });}
```

User Model

```
    public function ong(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Ong');

    }
```

OngsController has a store method

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->all();

        $request['user_id']= $id;

    }
```

but how can i get the 'user_id' in there?

i'm using Auth from laravel/ui auth

only have this route now but this goes to the form

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'web'],function(){
    Route::view('/criarOng', 'ongs.create');
});
```

Create form

```
{!! Form::open([
        'method'=>'post', 'route' => 'ongs.store'
    ]) !!}
    {!! Form::label('name', 'Nome da Ong') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name') !!}
    {!! Form::select('estado',['SP'=>'SP', 'RJ'=>'RJ'], null) !!}
    {!! Form::label('cidade', 'Cidade da ong') !!}
    {!! Form::text('cidade') !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Criar') !!}
    

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: use $request->user() for getting current logged in user instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup foreign key on ong table.

```
 Schema::create('ongs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('ong_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Then while creating ong you can use

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->all();

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    }
```

Then in your ONG Model

```
public function ong(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Ong');

    }
```